# My own strcat function with pointers does not work right

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strcat, function-definition

I am new to pointers and want to learn them well. So this is my own attempt to write my `strcat` function. If I return just `a` it prints some binary things (I think it should print the solution), If I return `*a` it says `seg fault core dumped` I couldn't find the error. Any help is accepted thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *strcaT();

    char *a = "first";

    char *b = "second";

    printf("%s", strcaT(a, b));

    return 0;
}

char *strcaT(char *t, char *s) {   
    char buffer[strlen(t) + strlen(s) - 1];

    char *a = &buffer[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s) + strlen(t); i++, t++) {
        if (*t == '\n') {
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s);i++) {
                buffer[strlen(t) + i] = *(s + i);
            }
        }
        buffer[i] = *(t + i);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: That must be `+`, not `-1` as `strlen` does nor count the terminating null character.

Comment: string terminating character is ``'\0'`` not ``'\n'``

Comment: `char* a = &buffer[0];` and then `return a`. -- That's a problem. You return the address of a local array. That array will be gone as soon as you leave the function.

Comment: I would like to add that not only returning pointer to local stack is UB, but the statement `char buffer[strlen(t) + strlen(s) - 1];` will not work on all compilers/configurations. It is non-standard. Try `malloc` to allocate memory on heap when the sizes are unknown at compile time.

Comment: I'd throw that code away and start over again because it is incredibly convoluted. `strcat` should be 3-4 lines maximum. Why do you care about `'\n'`? `strcat` doesn't do this.

Comment: @sorush-r: the variable length array is Standard C99, but you are correct, support for this is flaky or absent, especially on legacy systems and missing from C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has multiple cases of undefined behavior:

- you return the address of a local array in `strcaT` with automatic storage, which means this array can no longer be used once it goes out of scope, ie: when you return from the function.
- the buffer size is too small, it should be the sum of the lengths plus 1 for the null terminator. You write beyond the end of this local array, potentially overwriting some important information such as the caller's framce pointer or the return address. This undefined behavior has a high chance of causing a segmentation fault.
- you copy `strlen(t)+strlen(s)` bytes from the first string, accessing beyond the end of `t`.
- It is unclear why you test for `'\n'` and copy the second string at the position of the newline in the first string. Strings do not end with a newline, they may contain a newline but and at a null terminator (byte value `'\0'` or simply `0`). Strings read by `fgets()` may have a trailing newline just before the null terminator, but not all strings do. In your loop, the effect of copying the second string is immediately cancelled as you continue copying the bytes from the first string, even beyond its null terminator. You should perform these loops separately, first copying from `t`, then from `s`, regardless of whether either string contains newlines.

Also note that it is very bad style to declare `strcaT()` locally in `main()`, without even a proper prototype. Declare this function before the `main` function with its argument list.

Here is a modified version that allocates the concatenated string:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strcaT(const char *s1, const char *s2);

int main() {
    const char *a = "first";
    const char *b = "second";
    char *s = strcaT(a, b);
    if (s) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }
    return 0;
}

char *strcaT(const char *t, const char *s) {
    char *dest = malloc(strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1);
    if (dest) {
        char *p = dest;
        /* copy the first string */
        while (*t) {
            *p++ = *t++;
        }
        /* copy the second string at the end */
        while (*s) {
            *p++ = *s++;
        }
        *p = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Note however that this is not what the `strcat` function does: it copies the second string at the end of the first string, so there must be enough space after the end of the first string in its array for the second string to fit including the null terminator. The definitions for `a` and `b` in `main()` would be inappropriate for these semantics, you must make `a` an array, large enough to accommodate both strings.

Here is a modified version with this approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcaT(char *s1, const char *s2);

int main() {
    char a[12] = "first";
    const char *b = "second";
    printf("%s\n", strcaT(a, b));
    return 0;
}

char *strcaT(char *t, const char *s) {
    char *p = t;
    /* find the end of the first string */
    while (*p) {
        *p++;
    }
    /* copy the second string at the end */
    while (*s) {
        *p++ = *s++;
    }
    *p = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
    return t;
}
```

Comment: From the contents of the question, it is unclear whether OP thinks strings necessarily end with `'\n'` or there was some prior attempt to concatenate strings that did end with `’\n'` (and the initialization of `a` and `b` is the result of attempting to prepare a minimal reproducible example) or something else. Discussing this might improve an answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Good point. I updated the answer with a more specific discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to return some local variable, it will be cleared after the function finishes its operation. The following function should work.

```
char* strcaT(char *t, char *s)
{
    char *res = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1));

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++, count++)
        res[count] = t[i];

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++, count++)
        res[count] = s[i];

    res[count] = '\0';

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why `long` type for `count`? You should actually use `size_t` for all index variables

Comment: Sry ! my bad, habit of using long when developing generic applications. ``size_t`` I learn to develop that habit

Comment: Also avoid recomputing `strlen(t)`  and `strlen(s)` at each iteration: use `t[i] != '\0'` and `s[i] != '\0'` as loop tests.

Comment: You should probably try and lose this habit. `size_t` is the correct type, and it may be larger than `long`, for example on 64-bit Windows. The only trap is the unsignedness of `size_t`.

Comment: Local variables are not “cleared” when a function returns, except in special circumstances.

Comment: Yes, strlen() is an expensive operation, check for terminating character would be an efficient approach.

Comment: @MohithReddy: Per the C standard, storage (memory) is **reserved** for use for an object during its lifetime. When an object’s lifetime ends, all the C standard tells us is that storage is no longer reserved. It does not say the storage is cleared, deleted, or protected. Neither does it say the storage is not cleared, not deleted, or not protected. Common C implementations do the easiest thing: Release the storage for other use and not make any special provisions for it. However, compiler optimization may affect the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `strcaT` should append the string specified by the second parameter to the end of the string specified by the first parameter. So the first parameter should point to a character array large enough to store the appended string.

Your function is incorrect because at least it returns a (invalid) pointer to a local variable length character array that will not be alive after exiting the function and moreover the array has a less size than it is required to store two strings that is instead of

```
char buffer[strlen(t) + strlen(s) - 1];
                                 ^^^
```

it should be declared at least like

```
char buffer[strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1];
                                 ^^^
```

and could be declared as static

```
static char buffer[strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1];
```

Also the nested loops do not make sense.

Pay attention that you should provide the function prototype before calling the function. In this case the compiler will be able to check passed arguments to the function. And the name of the function `strcaT` is confusing. At least the function can be named like `strCat`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * strCat( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1 + strlen( s1 );

    while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 14 };
    char s1[N] = "first";
    char *s2 = "second";

    puts( strCat( s1, s2  ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
firstsecond
```

On the other hand if you are already using the standard C function `strlen` then why not to use another standard C function `strcpy`?

With this function your function could be defined more simpler like

```
char * strCat( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    strcpy( s1 + strlen( s1 ), s2 );

    return s1;
}
```

If you want to build a new character array that contains two strings one appended to another then the function can look for example the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * strCat( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );

    char *result = malloc( n1 + strlen( s2 ) + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( result, s1 );
        strcpy( result + n1, s2 );
    }       

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "first";
    char *s2 = "second";

    char *result = strCat( s1, s2 );

    if ( result ) puts( result );

    free( result );

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
firstsecond
```

Of course calls of the standard C function `strcpy` you can substitute for your own loops but this does not make great sense.

If you are not allowed to use standard C string functions then the function above can be implemented the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * strCat( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s1[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; )
    {
        n += ++i;
    }

    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        char *p = result;
        while ( ( *p = *s1++ ) != '\0' ) ++p;
        while ( ( *p = *s2++ ) != '\0' ) ++p;
    }       

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "first";
    char *s2 = "second";

    char *result = strCat( s1, s2 );

    if ( result ) puts( result );

    free( result );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main function

```
char *strcaT();
```

It should be declared before `main` function:

```
char *strcaT(char *t, char *s);
int main() {...}
```

You returns the local array `buffer[]`, it's is undefined behavior, because out of `strcaT` function, it maybe does not exist. You should use the pointer then allocate for it.

The size of your `buffer` should be `+1` not `-1` as you did in your code.

```
char *strcaT(char *t, char *s) {   
    char *a = malloc(strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1);
    if (!a) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        a[i] = t[i];
    }

    for(int j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++,i++) {
        a[i] = s[j];
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

The complete code for test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strcaT(char *t, char *s);

int main() {

    char *a = "first";
    char *b = "second";
    char *str = strcaT(a, b);
    if (str != NULL) {
       printf("%s\n", str);
       free(str); // Never forget freeing the pointer to avoid the memory leak
    }
    return 0;
}

char *strcaT(char *t, char *s) {   
    char *a = malloc(strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1);
    if (!a) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        a[i] = t[i];
    }

    for(int j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++,i++) {
        a[i] = s[j];
    }
    a[i] = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have changed your program to look like below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* strcaT();

    char* a = "first";

    char* b = "second";

    printf("%s",strcaT(a,b));

    return 0;
}
char* strcaT(char *t, char *s)
{   

    char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(t) + strlen(s) + 1));

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(t); i++) {
        a[i] = t[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) {
        a[strlen(t) + i] = s[i];
    }
    a[strlen(t)+strlen(s)] = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

You are getting segfault because you are returning address of a local array which is on stack and will be inaccessible after you return. Second is that your logic is complicated to concatenate the strings.

Comment: This is wrong: “You are getting segfault because you are returning address of a local array”. As stated in the question, the version of the program that returns the address of a local array does not get a segmentation fault; it prints incorrect data. The version of the program that gets a segmentation fault does not return the address of a local array; it returns the value of a `char` (where a pointer is needed).